# Using Grive to backup Links to large folder

Tags: backup, shotwell, grive

I have a folder that contains 2 Gig of photos for Shotwell that I want to backup using Grive. I created a Link to the folder and moved the link to the Google Drive folder.  When I run Sync Now, it processes for about 15 seconds, deletes the Link entry from the Google Drive folder and says Synchronization is complete.  No data is uploaded to Googledrive.com.

I have tested this procedure with a small folder and it works fine but fails on the large folder.

Shotwell can't find its source photos if I move this folder to Google Drive folder.  Is there a way to direct Shotwell to the photo folder in the Google Drive folder?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.  I would appreciate any help on this problem.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I'd like to sync my pictures folder to Drive, but I'm seeing the same behavior as you.